# Hide installation wizard after upgrade

Tags: install, ce-1.8.0.0, local.xml

From what I [read](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-installation-cheat-sheet) the installation wizard runs only if there is no `local.xml`. I do have this configuration:

```
ls -la app/etc/local.xml
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 apache apache 2317 Dec 10 12:31 app/etc/local.xml
```

But wizard is still showing up. I did an magento upgrade and don't like to do the wizard again. Clearing cache did not help.

How do I close the installation wizard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not exactly tested for local.xml.

Instead for the install date:

```
\Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::preDispatch
> \Mage::isInstalled

if (($date = $localConfig->global->install->date) && strtotime($date)) {
    self::$_isInstalled = true;
}
...
return self::$_isInstalled;
```

So adding a strtotime-readable date to `global/install/date` is enough

Answer (score 1):

I did not set the install date in local.xml. Have look in [app/Mage.php > isInstalled()](https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-design-training/blob/master/app/Mage.php#L523).